# Divide a webfrom textfield component into a specific input format

Tags: webforms

I have a need to divide a webform component into a specific formatting that is to match a coupon format. The user input needs to look something like this.

[image]

Then within the webfrom exported data the coupon needs to be displayed as one field.

Can anyone please suggest how this can be done or what the best practice is to achieve this within Drupal 7?

Thank you  - your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [jQuery masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) to mask the field input.
2. If you really want to have 3 separate fields, you can do that with JS again. Have one field (let's call it "main" field) where you will save the value and generate the other 3 on the fly. Hide main field and on change update the value by adding the values of those three fields.

Comment: @ Ivanhoe123 thanks for your direction with this. I really do need to have three separate fields. My JS is quite limited but I will search for an example of this method.

Comment: An example of the second method can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/xa5pj/ - After figuring it out form other examples I don't think this is worth +50! :) @Ivanhoe do you feel like I should give you +50 for this?

Comment: If my approach solved your problem then yes; it's up to you. Asking such question about imaginary reputation points on a professional portal seems funny though.

Comment: I agree, after reading what I wrote, it sounds funny to me also. I give it to you with pleasure. Thank you for your answer - it was much appreciated, as it did solve an my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Creditfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/creditfield) module can solve your issue. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... a small proof of concept module that provides 3 FormAPI elements to be used in the Drupal Form API for custom forms:
>
> - Credit Card Number
> - Credit Card Expiration Date
> - Credit Card CVV
>
> These fields provide basic validation and form errors on their own (including Luhn check against card number). You could easily add more within your own form validation callbacks as well.

Comment: @ Gladiator thanks for you link - I don't think this is able to do a format like i need.